Dummy-encoded PyArrow table from PyArrow ChunkedArray, without going through pandas?
Say I have
import pyarrow as pa

ca = pa.chunked_array([['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']])
print(ca)

<pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray object at 0x7fc938bcea70>
[
  [
    "a",
    "b",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
]

I'd like to end up with:
pyarrow.Table
_a: uint8
_b: uint8
_c: uint8
----
_a: [[1,0,0,0]]
_b: [[0,1,1,0]]
_c: [[0,0,0,1]]

How can I do this?
I'm aware that it's possible to do this by converting to pandas, but is it possible to do it with just PyArrow (to avoid taking on an extra dependency)?
EDIT: numpy is already a required dependency of PyArrow, so I'm OK with using that. However, it's not the idea solution, so a pure-NumPy solution would be best to avoid

This question is similar to: Convert array of indices to one-hot encoded array in NumPy. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you can use Pandas you could try something like pa.table(pandas.get_dummies(ca).astype("uint8")).

import pyarrow as pa

ca = pa.chunked_array([['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']])

unique_elements = ['a', 'b', 'c']

one_hot_columns = {f'_{elem}': [0] * len(ca.chunks[0]) for elem in unique_elements}

for chunk in ca.chunks:
    for i, value in enumerate(chunk.to_pylist()):
        for elem in unique_elements:
            one_hot_columns[f'_{elem}'][i] = 1 if value == elem else 0

one_hot_arrays = {key: pa.array(value, type=pa.uint8()) for key, value in one_hot_columns.items()}

table = pa.table(one_hot_arrays)

print(table)

Here is the code that works.
Steps:

Create the chunked array
Define the unique elements
Populate the one-hot encoded columns as uint8 arrays
Create the PyArrow table from these arrays


thanks - this works, I just worry about the cost of iterating through rows in Python

Using enumerate may minimise cost but, if you consider NumPy, that will be more efficient.

Yup, NumPy is fine to use, I've amended the question to make it clear - do you have a numpy solution?

Dictionary-encoding the array first transforms the task into one-hot encoding.
In []: da = ca.dictionary_encode().combine_chunks()
In []: da
Out[]: 
<pyarrow.lib.DictionaryArray object at 0x106dc2260>

-- dictionary:
  [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
-- indices:
  [
    0,
    1,
    1,
    2
  ]

In []: onehot = np.zeros((len(da.dictionary), len(da)), int)
In []: onehot[da.indices, np.arange(len(da))] = 1
In []: onehot
Out[]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

In []: pa.table(list(onehot), da.dictionary.to_pylist())
Out[]: 
pyarrow.Table
a: int64
b: int64
c: int64
----
a: [[1,0,0,0]]
b: [[0,1,1,0]]
c: [[0,0,0,1]]



Get the list of unique values (and possibly sort them).
For each unique value, calculate the one hot encoding array for that value
Make a table out of these arrays

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

ca = pa.chunked_array([["a", "b", "b", "c"]])

unique = ca.unique().sort()

columns = []
for value in unique:
    columns.append(pc.equal(ca, value))

table = pa.Table.from_arrays(columns, names=unique.to_pylist())




a
b
c




1
0
0


0
1
0


0
1
0


0
0
1



